# Import exisiting Logical Volume into Openstack

Tags: lvm, openstack, cinder

My Openstack (Microstack on Ubuntu) got screwed up and I had to reinstall it. Putting a backup of the Openstack config back in place didn't work so have to start "fresh".

The problem now is: I have my LV group "cinder-volumes" with all its Logical Volumes. But I can't seem to find a way to "import" these existing volumes into Openstack.

```
  ACTIVE            '/dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv' [<110.29 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/cinder-volumes/cinder-volumes-pool' [442.47 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/cinder-volumes/volume-67c6131b-027c-4630-9e7b-28fc58bba5b7' [1.00 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/cinder-volumes/volume-a97cb400-0d75-4e63-970f-aee85e9cf765' [20.00 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/cinder-volumes/volume-6dcec4d1-fe28-431d-b5b6-6486d0fb2c0e' [20.00 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/cinder-volumes/volume-d370bd24-48de-43c5-be5e-2b69587e1679' [20.00 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/cinder-volumes/volume-1414d413-39d6-4c54-abc6-4ecf1a2fe1bf' [20.00 GiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/cinder-volumes/_snapshot-77b443bf-22e9-4062-aeaa-82c6802c0930' [20.00 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/cinder-volumes/volume-0ffb52ac-f3d4-4269-b385-18b812ecddac' [<3.91 TiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/cinder-volumes/_snapshot-1af42d15-bce8-440b-a478-a0789a824dbc' [<3.91 TiB] inherit
```

The goal is to create new instances with these existing LV.

Is there a way to do this please?

EDIT: I do have recent sql database backups of Openstack.

Thank you

Comment: You could look into the `cinder manage` command to make existing volumes known to openstack. I have done this with ceph storage backend, I'm not sure if and how it works with LVM based volumes.

Comment: Thanks @eblock I did find some documentation on this procedure with CEPH but unfortunately not with LVM. I am amazed that not more people have (had) this issue. My next route will be to analyze the DB and see if I can put in some manual rows in the cinder tables with the right info. But I don't really like this approach.

Comment: I found instructions for [Pure Storage](https://blog.purestorage.com/purely-technical/hints-on-using-cinder-manage-with-openstack-newton-and-later/) and [Netapp](https://community.netapp.com/t5/OpenStack-Discussions/Cinder-manage-command/td-p/127839). The LVM backend is not for production use, which might explain why you have not found LVM instructions, but nothing prevents you from trying anyway.

Comment: Thank you @berndbausch especially the Pure Storage page seems very interesting. I didn't realize there was a difference between "cinder manage" and "cinder-manage". I'll look into it.